# How to set any variables for all cron jobs?

Tags: linux, cron

i've a lot of jobs in /etc/cron.d/ directory.
How can i set any variables (ex. MAILTO) globally, for all this cron jobs?

I set MAILTO=username in /etc/crontab, but its doesn't work for jobs in /etc/cron.d/

Answer (score 0):

You could store your settings in /etc/environment. That way, they will be used by all processes. See for example here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables.

Comment: Did you read the docs?  "It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line."

Comment: man 8 cron ENVIRONMENT:  If configured in /etc/default/cron in Debian systems, the cron daemon localisation settings environment can be managed through the use of  /etc/environment .. This does NOT affect the environment of tasks running under cron. SO! If i set MAILTO=admin in /etc/environment, this will not work